# how get a reference to a dynamically imported component in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Want to use a reference to a dynamically imported component in next js as below. How do I do this?

Given

```
// component1.jsx
export default class Component1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (<p>something</p>)    
    }
    doSomething() {
        console.log('should work')
    }
}
```

And

```
// component2.jsx
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const Component1 = dynamic(import('./component1'), {ssr: false})

class Component2 extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.myRef.current.doSomething(); // This fails!
}

render() {
    return (<Component1 ref={this.myRef}/>);
}
}
```

Already looked at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4957 and the solution there just doesn't work?

Comment: Have you specifically tried this workaround: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4957#issuecomment-413841689?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version of react/next. Perhaps the example hasn't been updated

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on the facts that `next/dynamic` is built on top of `React.lazy` & `React.Suspense`. This solution works in my case (loading a dropdown on client side only - option `ssr: false`).

```js
/**
 * Usage is the same as `dynamic()` from NextJS with 1 exception: `ssr` IS ALWAYS FALSE, hence the name of this function.
 * @param {() => any} importCallback Ex: () => import('./LazyComponent.jsx')
 * @param {{ loading?: () => import('react').ReactNode }} options This can be similar to options of `dynamic()` from NextJS
 */
export const clientOnly = (importCallback, { loading } = {}) => {
  const LazyComponent = lazy(importCallback);
  return forwardRef(function ClientOnlyComponent(props, forwardedRef) {
    const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
      setIsClient(true);
    }, []);
    return (
      isClient && (
        <Suspense fallback={loading?.()}>
          <LazyComponent
            {...props}
            ref={forwardedRef}
          />
        </Suspense>
      )
    );
  });
};
```

Then:

```js
// ComponentB.jsx
const LazyComponentA = clientOnly(()=> import('./componentA'));

// later, use component A as normal in NextJS:
export const ComponentB = () => {
  //...
  return <LazyComponentA />;
};
```

I have checked workaround in the github issue you mentioned & I still came up with this solution because I don't want to expose a special prop to contain ref (instead of official `React.forwardRef`) on my lazy-loaded component (then I have to write documentation/comment to explain why).